# How to populate json file with data from bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I am writing a small bash script and I am stuck. I have a text file with some information and I stored the contents of that file in a bash variable.

```
tools=$(cat tools.txt)
```

My `tools.txt` file looks like this:

```
docker:19.03.8
go:1.18
kubernetes:1.20
```

And so on.

What I want is to dynamically create a JSON file named `tools.json` and to populate that file with the content from `tools.txt`.

In my `tools.json` file I have the following structure:

```
{
    "tools": {

     }
}
```

And this should be the final structure.

```
{
    "tools": {
         "name" : "version"
     }
}
```

So the expected output is:

```
{
    "tools": {
         "docker" : "19.03.8",
         "go" : "1.18",
         "kubernetes" : "1.20"
     }
}
```

I don't know how to loop through the `$tools` variable or `tools.txt` file in such a way that on each iteration a new line (`"docker" : "19.03.8"`) is added to `tools.json` file.

I tried something like this

```
cat <<EOF > ./tools.json
{
   "tools": {
        for tool in $tools
        do
                "name" : "version",
        done
   }
}
EOF
```

Of course, it doesn't work. The idea is that instead of  `"name" : "version"` in a loop to use something like `"$name" : "$version"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tool "jq" for that.

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

I would do something like this:

```sh
cat > tools.json << EOF
{
    "tools": {

    }
}
EOF

for item in "${tools[@]}"; do
    tool=$(echo "$item" | cut -d ":" -f1)
    version=$(echo "$item" | cut -d ":" -f2)
    old_content=$(cat tools.json)

    echo "$old_content" | jq \
        --arg TOOL "$tool" \
        --arg VERSION "$version" \
        '.tools += { ($TOOL) : ($VERSION) }' \
        > tools.json
done
```

A better solution would be:

```sh
while IFS=":" read -r tool version; do
    old_content=$(cat tools.json)
    echo "$old_content" | jq \
        --arg TOOL "$tool" \
        --arg VERSION "$version" \
        '.tools += { ($TOOL) : ($VERSION) }' \
        > tools.json
done < tools.txt
```

Comment: I heard about that tool, but I am not sure how. I never used jq before. Can you give me a hint? I am also new to bash.

Comment: The great thing about `jq` over the other answers is that it is a very flexible tool to add more complex structures to JSON if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Bash parts of your code has some pesky beginner errors. Probably run it through http://shellcheck.net/ before posting here. Probably also look into using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) instead of the clumsy `variable=$(echo "value" | cut)`; or simply use `while IFS=":" read -r tool version; do .... done <file` to have `read` split the input lines into fields on colons.

Comment: I did this on purpose to make it look more clear since @norskprove also mentioned being new to bash.

Comment: @seldesjo Thank you. As a newbie, I really appreciate this. I am not sure if it's the best practice but it's a very clear step-by-step solution for a beginner like me.

Comment: @seldesjo How can I achieve the same thing with while loop? I would like to refactor this to avoid using `tool=$(echo "$item" | cut -d ":" -f1)` ,`version=$(echo "$item" | cut -d ":" -f2)` and `old_content=$(cat tools.json)`? What would be the best way to achive this?

Comment: @norskprove I edited the post with an example using "white read".

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with a simple bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "{"
echo "    \"tools\": {"

while IFS=: read -r name value
do
    echo "        $comma\"$name\": \"$value\""
    comma=","
done < tools.txt

echo "    }"
echo "}"
```

... just to demonstrate the principle.

Answer (score 0):

Using your already created `tools.json` file, you can try this `sed`

```
$ sed '/tools/{n;s!.*!tac tools.txt|sed "s/^/\t/;2,$ s/$/\\",/;s/$/\\"/"|tac!e};/[a-z]/s/\t\([^:]*\):/\t"\1" : "/g' tools.json
{
    "tools": {
        "docker" : "19.03.8",
        "go" : "1.18",
        "kubernetes" : "1.20"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is quite simple that you don't need `loop` or `jq`, you can use only commands and pipes:

```
λ cat tools.txt 
docker:19.03.8
go:1.18
kubernetes:1.20
```

```sh
printf '{"tools":{'$(
  tr : ' ' <tools.txt |
    xargs printf '"%s":"%s"\n' |
    paste -s -d , -
)'}}\n'
```

```
{"tools":{"docker":"19.03.8","go":"1.18","kubernetes":"1.20"}}
```

## Explanation

Use `tr` `xargs` `printf` and `paste` to generate the JSON `tools` body part:

```sh
tr : ' ' < tools.txt |
  xargs printf '"%s":"%s"\n' |
  paste -s -d , -
```

```
"docker":"19.03.8","go":"1.18","kubernetes":"1.20"
```

Prepend `'{"tools":{'` and append `'}}\n'` by `printf`:

```sh
printf '{"tools":{'$(YOUR COMMAND)'}}\n'
```